# Delphi QuantumGrid - rowChanged event?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I'm using the devExpress QuantumGrid, and I'm wondering that there is no onRowChange event.
How can I determine when the selected row has changed?

I could use the onCellClick event, but this isn't fired when the user scrolls with the cursor keys - It doesn't seem very suitable for that purpose.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TcxGridTableView` class owns the `OnSelectionChanged` event.

From the online help:

> Keep in mind the difference between
>   **selected** and **focused** records.  There
>   can be only one focused record within
>   a View at any time.  If the
>   View.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect
>   option is deactivated, then the
>   focused record is the selected record.
>   In this case, the **OnSelectionChanged**
>   event is not raised.  You need to
>   handle the **OnFocusedRecordChanged**
>   event instead.

Comment: Yes, I know - I tried this but onSelectionChange does not fire when I select another row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Dataset's event AfterScroll. It is fired when the current row of the dataset changes.

Comment: Hi, I allready tried this, but AfterScroll is also fired when the row hasn't changed (for example when data is loaded)...

Comment: You can work around that. When data is loaded the cxGrid disables the controls, so you can do: if MyDataSet.ControlsDisabled = False then DoWhatYouWant

Answer (score 0):

`OnFocusedRecordChanged` from the view